# Intellisense doesn't work on my webpack library

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

I publish a npm package by webpack library.
Now it works fine but there is no intellisense of my package on my vscode.
Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
// src/index.js
export {
  action
}
export default {
  someMethods
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'autoProTools',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    // libraryExport: 'default',
    globalObject: 'this'
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Intellisense work after add ```.d.ts``` file.